# Pandas, remove differences between 3 dataframes based on common column data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have 3 dataframes containing sensor data. I'm doing some cleanup of the data before I work with it further. I basically need to keep the common time data between the 3 datasets and discard the rows from each dataframe which are not in the others. I'm relatively new to pandas and before I use something like SQL I was wondering if there's any way to achieve this with pandas?

To give a better idea of what I mean here is a screenshot of the csv files in Excel I'm using in the dataframes:

[dataframe_csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWAtP.png)

As in the above screenshot due to the way I'm capturing the data I cannot synchronize the time exactly so while DF1 has the 01/05/2020  19:33:54 Timestamp, DF2 and DF3 do not but all dataframes will have the DF3 starting timestamp so I would want to remove the uncommon time column data values from all 3 dataframes. I will also have to do the same with the data at the end of each file.

Would this be possible?

Just to clarify the input and the output I need would be similar to the following:

```
DF1
Time        DeviceID SensorData
19:44:01    IMU1    0.26
19:44:02    IMU1    0.25
19:44:03    IMU1    0.25
19:44:04    IMU1    0.25


DF2
19:44:02    IMU2    0.27
19:44:03    IMU2    0.23
19:44:04    IMU2    0.22
19:44:05    IMU2    0.28

DF3
19:44:03    IMU3    0.23
19:44:04    IMU3    0.15
19:44:05    IMU3    0.07
19:44:06    IMU3    0.45

Output:
DF1
19:44:03    IMU1    0.25
19:44:04    IMU1    0.25

DF2
19:44:03    IMU2    0.23
19:44:04    IMU2    0.22

DF3
19:44:03    IMU3    0.23
19:44:04    IMU3    0.15
```

But this needs to be done for each dataframe as I need to use them separately at first.

Comment: Please give a sample input and expected output.

Comment: Please don't paste it in comment. Paste it in question itself.

Comment: Yes, sorry just updated it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering all your dataframes(df1,df2,df3) have same column names, you can do this:

```
In [1130]: s = df1.merge(df2,on='Time').merge(df3,on='Time')['Time']

In [1134]: df1 = df1[df1.Time.isin(s)]                                                                                                                                                                      

In [1135]: df2 = df2[df2.Time.isin(s)]                                                                                                                                                                      

In [1136]: df3 = df3[df3.Time.isin(s)]                                                                                                                                                                      

In [1137]: df1                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[1137]: 
       Time DeviceID  SensorData
2  19:44:03     IMU1        0.25
3  19:44:04     IMU1        0.25

In [1138]: df2                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[1138]: 
       Time DeviceID  SensorData
1  19:44:03     IMU2        0.23
2  19:44:04     IMU2        0.22

In [1139]: df3                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[1139]: 
       Time DeviceID  SensorData
0  19:44:03     IMU3        0.23
1  19:44:04     IMU3        0.15
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it worked on a sample of my dataset. However when I tried to use this on the full set I began to get errors stating the dataframe was too large to fit in memory. Since the differences I'm trying to merge are primarily at the start and end of the 3 dataframes could I use df.head() or df.tail() to do the same procedure or would I have to use something like chunked?